# string split on single strings works, but not on series of strings in pandas

Tags: python, excel, string, pandas, split

I'm very new to python & pandas and have an issue.
I have a series of 45398 strings which i need to edit. I imported them from an excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd

file_location = "#mypath/leistungen_2017.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)`

df = pd.read_excel("leistungen_2017.xlsx")
```

Here are the first few rows, just as example.

```
>>> df
Leistungserbringer  Anzahl  Leistung    Code    Rechnungsnummer
0   Albert  1   15.0160 Vollständige Spirometrie und Resistanc...   1   8957
1   Albert  1   15.0200 CO-Diffusion, jede Methode  1   8957
2   Albert  1   15.0285 Messung ausgeatmetes Stickstoffmonoxid...   1   8957
3   Albert  1   AMC-30864 Spirometriefilter mit Mundstück   1   8957
4   Albert  1   5889797 RELVAR ELLIPTA Inh Plv 92mcg/22mcg 30 Dos   1   8957
5   Albert  1   00.0010 Konsultation, erste 5 Min. (Grundkonsu...   1   8957
```

In the fourth column, there are a bunch of numbers in front of the text and I want to remove them for the whole series.

I tested around with single strings and it works fine with:

```
>>> str("15.0200 CO-Diffusion, jede Methode".split(' ', 1)[1:]).strip('[]')`
"'CO-Diffusion, jede Methode'"
```

I tried to apply this to the whole series with:

```
for entry in df.Leistung:
    df.Leistung.replace({entry : str(entry.split(' ', 1)[1:]).strip('[]')},  inplace=True)
```

The outcome for df.Leistung should look something like this:

```
0        Vollständige Spirometrie und Resistance (Plet...
1                             CO-Diffusion, jede Methode
2         Messung ausgeatmetes Stickstoffmonoxid ({eNO})
3                        Spirometriefilter mit Mundstück
4              RELVAR ELLIPTA Inh Plv 92mcg/22mcg 30 Dos
5         Konsultation, erste 5 Min. (Grundkonsultation)
```

Instead, I receive this:

```
0                                                         
1                                                         
2                                                         
3                                                         
4                                                         
5
```

One row gives this:

```
45384    'Dos\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'"\\\\\\\\\...
```

I would need to update the old series with the new series in the same column.
I hope this was understandable and thank you in advance for posting any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need loops in pandas, it's all vectorised.  The replace function you are after falls under the **`.str.`** namespace.  So you need to do ::

```
df.Leistung.str.replace(r'\d+', '')
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, works perfectly!
There is still a "." at the start of each sentence, but ill remove that too. I'd upvote your comment, but my score is too low for that.